# How can I prove that $1+x \geq \exp({x/(1+x)})$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am dilemma how can I prove that $1+x \geq \exp({x/(1+x)})$. Any hints and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$? Clearly, it is false for $x=0$.

Comment: @amWhy Your edit seems to have changed the question.

Comment: @user17762 back to original question, with some added formatting.

Comment: I reverted an edit that removed all content. Please do not do this.

Answer (score 5):

Use that $\exp x \geq 1 + x$.  For $x > -1$ the inequality $$1-\frac{x}{x+1} > 0$$ holds and in this case we have the estimate
$$\exp \frac{x}{1+x} = \frac{1}{\exp \frac{-x}{1+x}} \leq \frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{1+x}}=1+x.
$$